# Changing string to uppercase in python

Tags: python, python-3.6

I' trying to change my variable to uppercase and I don't know what I'm getting wrong.  Sample code:

```
Quacks = "time"
Quacks.upper()
print(Quacks)
```

When I run the above code, `time` is returned instead of `TIME`.

Comment: save the result back into itself. Quacks = Quacks.upper() maybe?

Answer (score 3):

Method [upper()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_upper.asp) does not change the value of variable, it only returns a string where all characters are in upper case.

So, you may print it directly:

```
print(Quacks.upper())
```

or change first and then print:

```
Quacks = Quacks.upper()
print(Quacks)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python `str.upper()` returns a copy of the string with upper case values, and does not mutate the original string. In fact, strings in Python are [immutable](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/CS152f17/Strings/StringsareImmutable.html) anyways.

Try: `Quacks = Quacks.upper()`

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html

"`str.upper() - Return a copy of the string with all the cased characters [...] converted to uppercase.`"